# Which is more optimal, infinite recursion or infinite loops?

Tags: python, loops, recursion, optimization

I'm creating an application in Python that should run in the background making constant checks on the system clipboard. In order to achieve this, I have a method that makes the check and then calls itself after a specified delay (infinite recursion). However, I'm wondering if it would be more optimal to implement an infinite loop rather than recursion.

My first instinct is that a loop might be better because it doesn't retain any pointers to the previous function call - but I'm not really sure.

In short, is this more optimal:

```
def recursive(interval):
    performChecks()
    updateGUI()
    wait(interval)
    recursive(interval)
```

or is this

```
def main():
    running = True
    while running:
        performChecks()
        updateGUI()
        wait(interval)
```

Comment: That depends... do you have infinite space?

Comment: Optimal is a superlative! *scnr*

Comment: I suppose by optimal I mean the least amount of CPU usage in this scenario.

Comment: Very language-specific. In Scheme (or another language with TCO), the two would be exactly identical. (And in some languages without automatic TCO, there's still a construct that does an efficient jump backwards, such as Clojure's `loop`/`recur`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, you should prefer the second version.  This is because the call stack is by default limited to:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrecursionlimit()
1000
```

So your first approach will crash after 1000 iterations.